# Adding non-grouped attributes to row items in pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am often building pivot table reports for users for products or customers. Users often request that additional information be displayed within the pivot table for those row items. For example, in a pivot table showing item sales by year, they want me to include a column that shows what TYPE of item it is or who the author is. These attributes are additional properties of the item, and they are 1:1 for each item. I don't want them to be grouped. How can I do this?

For example This is a pivot of books by year. How do I add the author attribute without grouping it?

```
Title          | Author      | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | Totals
Awesome Book   | J. T. Joel  | 100  | 120  | 90   | 320
Crappy Book    | Karl Klapp  | 50   | 40   | 10   | 100
```

I'm used to doing this pretty easily in SQL, so I'm confused as to why it is hard in this context? Probably I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how pivots work, but maybe I'm just missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried *PivotTable Options* | *Display* | *Classic PivotTable layout* and also, if desired, unchecking *Show expand/collapse buttons*?

Comment: It appears you are my hero! I'll have to play a bit more, but I think this is exactly what I need at first glance. Thank you!